# How do I get notification for my own questions here?

Tags: discussion, notifications, stack-overflow

How do I get notifications when someone answers or comments on my question here?

Answer (score 2):

The little hamburger bubble next to StackExchange at the top left corner of the page will turn red to indicate things worthy of attention.  [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: hm..I found that previously. But it doesn't have the option of sending an email notification when here's an event update?

Comment: Have you checked "Allow email notifications when I subscribe to questions or tags" under "prefs" in your user profile?  Click on StackExchange at the top of the page and then "email settings" at the bottom of the box that opens.  That ought to help, but not too promptly.

Comment: mmmmm... hamburger bubble.....